# Why does this bash script not work as I want

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script

```
for s in $(ls -1 fig/*.py); do
   name=`basename $s .py`
   if [ -e "fig/$name.pdf" -o "fig/$name.pdf" -ot "fig/$name.data" -ot "fig/$name.py" ]; then
      $s
   fi
done
```

It is supposed to invoke a python script if the output pdf does not exist, or the pdf is older than the py or data file.

Unfortunaly, the script is now never invoked. What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks Benoit! My final script is:

```
for s in fig/*.py ; do # */ fix highlighting
    name="$(basename "$s" .py)"
    if test ! -e "fig/$name.pdf" -o "fig/$name.pdf" -ot "fig/$name.data" -o "fig/$name.pdf" -ot "fig/$name.py"
    then
        "$s"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many mistakes. See [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) especially first one (never rely on `ls` to get a list of files).

It also seems that the test is not well-formed: Two `-ot` in a row seem strange to me. Using `-o` to perform an OR instead of an AND seems weird also.

```
for s in fig/*.py ; do           # */ for code colouring on SO
    name="$(basename "$s" .py)"
    if test -e "fig/$name.pdf" -o "fig/$name.pdf" -ot "fig/$name.data" -ot "fig/$name.py"
    then
        "$s"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Sorry, at first I copied things wrong from my editor. Could you update your answer?

Comment: Thanks!! I see that I really messed up a bit with the or operators and so. I should rewrite it myself to negate the -e operator and to add an -o between the to -o statements